# Saving bounding box coordinates and images based on the class type into a different folder

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I'm using OpenCV + Python to apply a deep learning model and classify objects in 8 categories (animal types) namely, cat, dog, horse, deer, bear, lizard, monkey, no object detected (when the is no object detected in the image).

I have a folder that has images of all types of animals in it. I read all the images in one folder and then I apply the deep learning model to extract bounding box coordinates of each object in each image.

I want to first categorize each image by putting each type of animal image in the related folder. second, save the coordinate of the bounding box of that image in the same folder. For example if the network detected cat, I want to save that image and corresponding coordinates(as a text file .text) in the cat folder and if it did not find any of those objects in the image just put it in the no object detected folder.

My question is how can I save the original image and the bounding box coordinates of that object inside the 8 category folder?

here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import argparse
import time

img_dir="/path/imgt/"
data_path=os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files=glob.glob(data_path)
data=[]

i = 0
for f1 in files:
     image=cv2.imread(f1)
     data.append(image)

     # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
     ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
                     help="path to input image")
     ap.add_argument("-y", "--yolo", required=True,
                     help="base path to YOLO directory")
     ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
                     help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
     ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=0.3,
                     help="threshold when applyong non-maxima suppression")
     args = vars(ap.parse_args())

     # load the COCO class labels our YOLO model was trained on
     labelsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "obj.names"])
     LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")

     # initialize a list of colors to represent each possible class label
     np.random.seed(42)
     COLORS = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(LABELS), 3),
                                dtype="uint8")

     # derive the paths to the YOLO weights and model configuration
     weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolo-obj_last.weights"])
     configPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolo-obj.cfg"])

     # load our YOLO object detector trained on COCO dataset (80 classes)
     print("[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...")
     net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)

     # load our input image and grab its spatial dimensions
    # image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
     (H, W) = image.shape[:2]

     # determine only the *output* layer names that we need from YOLO
     ln = net.getLayerNames()
     ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

     # construct a blob from the input image and then perform a forward
     # pass of the YOLO object detector, giving us our bounding boxes and
     # associated probabilities
     blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
                                  swapRB=True, crop=False)
     net.setInput(blob)
     start = time.time()
     layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)
     end = time.time()

     # show timing information on YOLO
     print("[INFO] YOLO took {:.6f} seconds".format(end - start))

     # initialize our lists of detected bounding boxes, confidences, and
     # class IDs, respectively
     boxes = []
     confidences = []
     classIDs = []

     # loop over each of the layer outputs
     for output in layerOutputs:
          # loop over each of the detections
          for detection in output:
               # extract the class ID and confidence (i.e., probability) of
               # the current object detection
               scores = detection[5:]
               classID = np.argmax(scores)
               confidence = scores[classID]

               # filter out weak predictions by ensuring the detected
               # probability is greater than the minimum probability
               if confidence > args["confidence"]:
                    # scale the bounding box coordinates back relative to the
                    # size of the image, keeping in mind that YOLO actually
                    # returns the center (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding
                    # box followed by the boxes' width and height
                    box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
                    (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")

                    # use the center (x, y)-coordinates to derive the top and
                    # and left corner of the bounding box
                    x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
                    y = int(centerY - (height / 2))

                    # update our list of bounding box coordinates, confidences,
                    # and class IDs
                    boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
                    confidences.append(float(confidence))
                    classIDs.append(classID)

     # apply non-maxima suppression to suppress weak, overlapping bounding
     # boxes
     idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, args["confidence"],
                             args["threshold"])

     # ensure at least one detection exists
     if len(idxs) > 0:
          # loop over the indexes we are keeping
          for i in idxs.flatten():
               # extract the bounding box coordinates
               (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
               (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])

               # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the image
               color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
               cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
               text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
               cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 7), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.6, color, 2)
               path = '/path/imgr/' + LABELS[classIDs[i]] + '/'
               cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'image' + str(i) + '.jpg'), image)
               with open(os.path.join(path, 'image' + str(i) + '.txt'), 'a+') as f:
                 f.write(str(classIDs[i]) + ' ' + str(x) + ' ' + str(y) + ' ' + str(w) + ' ' + str(h))
```

**how does the text file look like?**

`.txt` -file for each `.jpg`-image-file - in the same directory and with the same name, but with `.txt`-extension, and put to file: object number and object coordinates on this image, for each object in new line: `<object-class> <x> <y> <width> <height>`
Where:
`<object-class>` - integer number of object from `0` to `(classes-1)`
`<x> <y> <width> <height>` - float values relative to width and height of image, it can be equal from `(0.0 to 1.0]`
for example: `<x> = <absolute_x> / <image_width> or <height> = <absolute_height> / <image_height>`
atention: `<x> <y>` - are center of rectangle (are not top-left corner)
For example for `img1.jpg` you will be created `img1.txt` containing:

```
1 0.716797 0.395833 0.216406 0.147222
0 0.687109 0.379167 0.255469 0.158333
1 0.420312 0.395833 0.140625 0.166667
```

Comment: in my opinion, this does not represent a real question. you present some code that does something and basically are tasking the SO community with completing your project. see the link: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/YoloObjectDetection/yolo.py  for code that looks exactly what *your* code looks like. you should not present other people's code as your own and simply ask this amazing community to code the rest for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
 path = os.path.join('/path/imgr/', LABELS[classID], image_name)
 cv2.imwrite(path + '.jpg', image)
 with open(path + '.txt'), 'a+') as f:
    f.write(str(classID) + ' ' + str(detection[0]) + ' ' + str(detection[1]) + ' ' + str(detection[2]) + ' ' + str(detection[3]) + '\n')
```

You may have multiple objects in an image, in which case it should write to each of the relevant folders and append to the text file if it exists.

`image_name` will be something you generate, you can use the name that you are reading in, or a counter.

This snippet should go somewhere under the if statement:

```
if confidence > args["confidence"]:
```

I would put it at the end.  You may need to make minor adjustments, but that is the gist.

---

More explicitly:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import argparse
import time

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
#                help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-y", "--yolo", required=True,
                help="base path to YOLO directory")  
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
                help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=0.3,
                help="threshold when applyong non-maxima suppression")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the COCO class labels our YOLO model was trained on
labelsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "obj.names"])
LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")

# derive the paths to the YOLO weights and model configuration
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolo-obj_last.weights"])
configPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolo-obj.cfg"])

# load our YOLO object detector trained on COCO dataset (80 classes)
print("[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)

# determine only the *output* layer names that we need from YOLO
ln = net.getLayerNames()
ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

img_dir="/path/imgt/"
data_path=os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files=glob.glob(data_path)

for f1 in files:
    # load our input image and grab its spatial dimensions
    image=cv2.imread(f1)

    # construct a blob from the input image and then perform a forward
    # pass of the YOLO object detector, giving us our bounding boxes and
    # associated probabilities
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
                                 swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)

    # loop over each of the layer outputs
    for output in layerOutputs:
         # loop over each of the detections
         for detection in output:
              # extract the class ID and confidence (i.e., probability) of
              # the current object detection
              scores = detection[5:]
              classID = np.argmax(scores)
              confidence = scores[classID]
              box = detection[0:4]
              # get upper left corner
              box[0] = box[0] - box[2]/2
              box[1] = box[1] - box[3]/2

              # filter out weak predictions by ensuring the detected
              # probability is greater than the minimum probability
              if confidence > args["confidence"]:
                  # write output files
                  class_dir = os.path.join('/path/imgr/', LABELS[classID])
                  if not os.path.exists(class_dir):
                      os.makedirs(class_dir)
                  path = os.path.join(class_dir, f1.split('/')[-1][:-4])
                  cv2.imwrite(path + '.jpg', image)
                  with open(path + '.txt'), 'a+') as f:
                      f.write(str(classID) + ' ' + str(box[0]) + ' ' + str(box[1]) + ' ' + str(box[2]) + ' ' + str(box[3]) + '\n')
```

Read through it and make sure you understand what each part in the for loop is doing.  Once you are comfortable with this minimal example you could add back in the non-maximal suppression and drawing the bounding boxes if you like.

Comment: I tried it, it did not work properly. The problem is that it puts one image in the folder and then puts the text file for the next image. The text files that generate are not correct. I updated my post. pls, review it.

Comment: Your white space is wrong, indent the last few lines to be flush with your call to `cv.putText`, it needs to be part of that for loop that your are iterating over i

Comment: I did that as well, unfortunately, it does output coordinates and images correctly. I edited the code,pls see it.

Comment: you say the text files it generates are not correct, can you provide an example of how they look?

Comment: they should look like what I explained in my post. but now it is like this:  0 88 4 724 6210 50 5 668 5610 64 -1 721 6170 73 0 716 5910 22 3 599 5100 40 1 732 6180 90 5 727 6230 123 10 900 6710 69 7 871 6810 399 58 731 678

Comment: another on is this 0 347 1 205 43

Comment: I've updated to include a newline character and the bounding box points before they are converted to pixels.

Comment: @ shortcipher3, I do not understand your approach, I am still getting errors, could you please edit my code based on your comment? I have edited my code and put the entire code.